Copy files from Windows Host to Docker Image in DockerFile
UPDATE: Copying files from the host to the build image isn't permitted and I think that important but less mentioned on answers like this.  I needed to start the image can docker cp into the running container. I then docker commit with a tag and no I have the files in an image.  I can from that point use COPY in the following Dockerfile.  The files will show in the Files tab.
I'm having an issue copying files into a new image that I can't find here.  I've looked at other posts but they don't seem to work such as this one.  I am using Linux containers on a Windows host.  I have copied the files I need into a folder on the root context of the Dockerfile. I even took one file and put it on the root context.  I can copy the files into a container using docker cp but I want these files in the image.  I tried ADD with the same results.  I don't have a .dockerignore file.  The image builds fine without the COPY commandlet.
I get this error:
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref |sha redacted|::|sha redacted|: "/mytext.txt": not found
My structure in the context is as follows (how I would like to use it)

DockerFile
    +
    -- /mydirectory
       + 
       --  mytext.txt

I have tried the following commandlets:
This works
WORKDIR /mydirectory
These don't work below the WORKDIR commandlet
COPY . . <- pull everything in the workdir from host to image (I want this behavior)
Another way 1
COPY mytext.txt /mydirectory
Another way 2
COPY mytext.txt . <- I copied it to the root context instead of the subdir
Another way 3
COPY mytext.txt ./
Another way 4
COPY c:/project/mydirectory/mytext.txt /mydirectory
Another way 5
COPY c:/project/mydirectory/mytext.txt .

For now I copied the files to a container and committed it.  There is probably an easier and more best practice friendly way, but this works for now.  I can create containers from this new image.

The left-hand side of COPY is always relative to the top-level build-context directory (and must be within that filesystem tree, not a parent or sibling directory).  WORKDIR changes the current directory in the image, which can include the destination of COPY, but it has no effect on the source.
That is, with the build-context layout you show, you always must write
COPY mydirectory/mytext.txt /some/container/path/

If the right-hand side of COPY is a relative path, that is affected by WORKDIR, but not the left-hand side.
# Using absolute paths:
COPY mydirectory/mytext.txt /app/mydirectory/

# Equivalently:
WORKDIR /app/mydirectory
COPY mydirectory/mytext.txt ./

There's no way within a Dockerfile to "narrow" the build context to some specific directory.  There are some patterns with trying to build an image out of multiple source trees that require the build-context directory to be a parent directory of the actual application you're trying to package, and you always need to use a path relative to that parent directory on the left-hand side of COPY.

Your advice isn't working.  I put mytext.txt in the same folder as the DockerFile.  and used this command in the file.    I'll be happy to get 1 file working.
With the same result "/mytext.txt" not found
COPY mytext.txt ./
FWIW thank you for responding
